# How does webpack-encore works with symfony 5?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack-encore

I'm getting a bit mad dealing with webpack-encore in a symfony 5 project.
There is few things i just don't understand. first of all here is my webpack.config.js :

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" 
command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
   Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
// public path used by the web server to access the output path
.setPublicPath('/build')
// only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
//.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

/*
 * ENTRY CONFIG
 *
 * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
 * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
 */
.addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

// enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
.enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

// When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
.splitEntryChunks()

// will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
// but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

/*
 * FEATURE CONFIG
 *
 * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
 * list of features, see:
 * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
 */
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableBuildNotifications()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
// enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

.configureBabel((config) => {
    config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
})

// enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
.configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
    config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
    config.corejs = 3;
})

// enables Sass/SCSS support
//.enableSassLoader()

// uncomment if you use TypeScript
//.enableTypeScriptLoader()

// uncomment if you use React
//.enableReactPreset()

// uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
// requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
//.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
//.autoProvidejQuery();

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

The thing is when i use {{ asset('build/images/my-image.png') }} in my template the file is not found though it is in assets/images/my-image.png

How should i access my image???
Why it is not in manifest.json ??
Why am i not having images in my public/build/ folder ?
What path should i be using to reference my image in app.css as a background-image for example ?

This thing is a nightmare to use  & configure.....
Thanks in advance

Comment: The [`copyFiles`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html#referencing-image-files-from-a-template) section of your config seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tryed run command for build files npm run build ?

or run command for recompile automatically assets
how of documentation exemple
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys you are both right,

```
   .copyFiles({
    from: './assets/images',
    // optional target path, relative to the output dir
    to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
    
    // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
    //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',

    // only copy files matching this pattern
    //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
})
```

this part was missing in my config files, then i did not run the build command.....

But it still not an easy tool.
Have a good day.